# How to loop through a JavaScript object with a condition and then output the data?

Tags: javascript, loops, object, conditional-statements

I've made two vehicles:

```
var manana = {name: "manana", price: "$8,000", slots: "4"};
var walton = {name: "walton", price: "$12,000", slots: "7"};
```

Reacting to a button click, I would like to check a condition, to see which vehicle has e.g. both its price equal to $8,000 and also slots equal to 4. If it does, it would output it in a table.

Comment: What did you try ? Can you post your code ? You can start by putting your objects in a array.

Comment: Well, that's one of my main issues really! I don't know where to start. I wanted to loop through it, but then I realised it doesn't work like that as I've just declared an array with its own objects.

Basically, I would like to know, to start off, how can I basically do this?

var vehicles: [
ar manana = {name: "manana", price: "$8,000", slots: "4"};
var walton = {name: "walton", price: "$12,000", slots: "7"};
]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to make it more readable, but it's still very vague. You might want to edit to include what you tried, why you thought it would work, and why it didn't. Good luck!

Comment: What language/syntax is `var vehicles: [ar manana = {`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to hook up an event on a button.  And then loop through your vehicles and test for a condition.  Something like:

```
var manana = {name: "manana", price: "$8,000", slots: "4"};
var walton = {name: "walton", price: "$12,000", slots: "7"};

var vehicles = [manana, walton];

function eval() {
    for (var i = 0; i < vehicles.length; i++) {
        var vehicle = vehicles[i];

        if (vehicle.price == '$8,000' && vehicle.slots == '4')
            alert('found ' + vehicle.name);
    }
}
```

Here is the JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/10qjw1gm/1/

Comment: Sorry, one more question. I tried to add more cars, but it only outputted manana, could you please show me how I can output all of the cars with the stated value?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my answer, you can reuse the fonction with different prices and slots conditions or an other array :

```
var myArray = [{name: "manana", price: "$8,000", slots: "4"}, {name: "walton", price: "$12,000", slots: "7"}];

function retrieveNameUsingPriceAndSlots(pArray, pPrice, pSlots) {
    for(var i = 0; i < pArray.length; i++) { //Loop through the array
        var item = pArray[i];
        if(item.price === pPrice && item.slots === pSlots) {
            //If the item meets our condition, returns the name, and the code after this line wont be executed.
            return item.name;
        }
    }

    return false; 
}

console.log(retrieveNameUsingPriceAndSlots(myArray, "$8,000", "4")); //manana
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/g2zuhou0/